# Converting a android phone to a satellite phone

Tags: android-emulator, android-versions

Is there something that you can buy that will convert your android phone (specifically a Samsung Galaxy 8 edge) into a satellite phone?  If so what are the advantages?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, [SatSleeve+](https://www.thuraya.com/satsleeve-plus) from [Thuraya](https://www.thuraya.com) comes with a universal adaptor in the package that allows you to switch between various Android and iPhone phone models between 58 and 85mm in width.